# Are there any resources for coding Gaussian Processes in R?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, regression, bayesian, gaussian-process

I am coding one, but the results just don't like as they should. Is there a resource out there that manually performs GP regression on a toy example? Like, do they 1) create the distance function 2) Train data 3) Optimize the hyperparameters 4) Calculate the conditional distribution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`plgp` is one of the libraries in `R` that can be used for implementation of Gaussian process regression:

Sample data generation with 6 (training) datapoints in 1D:

```
library(plgp)
library(mvtnorm)

f <- function(x) {
  return (cos(x))
}

eps <- sqrt(.Machine$double.eps) 

set.seed(1)
n <- 6 # number of training datapoints
X <- matrix(sort(runif(n, 0, 2*pi)), ncol=1)
y <- f(X)
```

Create the distance function (use exponential kernel for covariance) and train the GP:

```
s <- 1 # the `scale` hyperparameter for the exponential Kernel
D <- distance(X) # Euclidean
Sigma <- exp(-D / s) + diag(eps, ncol(D)) # make the covriance PSD
```

Compute the conditional distribution / GP posteriror / predictive distriution:

```
N <- 100 # number of test datapoints

XX <- matrix(seq(-0.5, 2*pi + 0.5, length=N), ncol=1)
DXX <- distance(XX)
SXX <- exp(-DXX) + diag(eps, ncol(DXX))

DX <- distance(XX, X)
SX <- exp(-DX)

Si <- round(solve(Sigma), 1)
# posterior update of mean and covariance matrix, given the data
mu_post <- SX %*% Si %*% y
Sigma_post <- SXX - SX %*% Si %*% t(SX)

YY <- rmvnorm(N, mu_post, Sigma_post)

q1 <- mu_post + qnorm(0.05, 0, sqrt(diag(Sigma_post)))
q2 <- mu_post + qnorm(0.95, 0, sqrt(diag(Sigma_post)))

matplot(XX, t(YY), type="l", col="lightgray", lty=1, xlab="x", ylab="y", main='Prediction with GP posterior')
points(X, y, col='blue', pch=20, cex=2)
lines(XX, f(XX), col="blue", lwd=2)
lines(XX, mu_post, col='red', lwd=2)
lines(XX, q1, lwd=2, lty=2, col=2)
lines(XX, q2, lwd=2, lty=2, col=2)
grid()
legend(x = "topleft", 
       legend=c("original", "predicted", "95% CI"), 
       col = c("blue","red", "red"),
       lty = c(1, 1, 2))
```

[image]

Note the increase / decrease of uncertainty in the specific intervals, as expected.

For hyperparameter (e.g., scale for the kernel) the `optimize()` function can be used to maximize a log0likelihood: refer to [this](https://bookdown.org/rbg/surrogates/chap5.html).

Comment: Thank you. I had already coded this manually, however this distance function would have been nice to know. So, if I have two input variables, I can make my X matrix with two columns and then it'd automatically calculate the Euclidean distances for me? That's neat!

Comment: One problem I often has is getting singularity when optimizing the hyperparameters. I don't see where I can do that with this package.

Comment: If the covariance matrix is singular, adding smalll noise with diagonal removes singularity